# How generate days like day 1, day 2,day-3 from particular date to date in Sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I have a requirement lets say the below start date 14-09-2022 to 23-10-2022, these dates has convert like Day 1,Day 2, Day 3, Etc. in SQL or Big query

```
**Input date:**

**Date**     **Day**
14-09-2022  Day 1,
15-09-2022  Day 2,
16-09-2022  Day 3,
17-09-2022  Day 4,
18-09-2022  Day 5,
19-09-2022  Day 6,
20-09-2022  Day 7,
.   
.   
23-10-2022  Day 39,
```

Sample output
[image]

Comment: use a numbers table....

Comment: How ?, Can you give me an Example

Comment: try googling what I said

Comment: What DB exactly used? MySQL or BigQuery?

Comment: Its a BigQuery Platform

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT dates
  ,concat("Day ", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dates)) day
FROM sample_data
```

The above will only work if you've pre-selected your date range via some kind of sub-select or CTE.  With the sample data you provided, the following will be produced:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can use `DATE_DIFF`

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(DATE '2022-09-20', DATE '2022-09-13', DAY) AS days_diff;
```

Comment: This will return only difference between dates. but I need to keep like Day 1, Day 2,..Etc

Comment: @GovindaRaju Cast the number to a char and prepend it with 'Day '